# Can I get a lightning with chanelling trident during a storm in a no-rain biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My base is at the edge of a savanna biome, some corners sticking out into other biomes. When I get storms, the sky gets dark, I hear thunder strikes, most of the area remains dry though, only some farms on the edge getting rain and lightning strikes.

I wanted to get into making mob heads through blowing the mobs up with charged creepers made by hitting them with a Channeling trident during a storm.

Thing is my mob grinder is the farthest from the non-savanna biomes, and transporting creepers a long distance is rather tricky. I'd just rather channel some mobs out of the grinder into an open blast-proof area nearby,   and perform the operation there. Will it work though? Does Channeling require a storm *with rain* or can it be used in a dry biome?

Java Edition 1.13.2, PC.

Comment: If you had just tried it and then shared the result as a self-answer, I would have applauded your effort to share your knowledge. But since you only asked, I wonder why you didn't just try it. It should just take a minute. (And no, I can't try it right now, I'm not on a computer with Minecraft on it.)

Comment: @FabianRöling 'cause since I got the idea I had one storm and it ended before I got to the trident, never mind finding some mobs under the open sky.

Comment: You know about Creative mode and the `/weather` command, right?

Comment: @FabianRöling: I *know* about them. I just tend to think about them as something that happens to other people.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes** it is possible.

I loaded up a creative world, enchanted a trident, and found a desert. I changed the weather to thunder and threw the trident at a sheep. The lightning was summoned. I tried it in clear weather and there was no lightning.

Also, because I was in the desert there was no rain and the trident worked anyway.

Comment: d'oh, I'm so deep into survival I forget Creative can be used for other purposes than testing self-destructive redstone contraptions.

Comment: Sometimes answers are right in front of us but we take the long route without realising haha.

Comment: Re your last sentence: Tridents in general do work outside of rain. It's Riptide that requires rain. (Not sure if Impaling works with rain or strictly requires underwater.)